# Exm email body not allowing adding components and links in Email body

Tags: exm

I am using Simple HTML Message as the Template to create my email. Layout is Text Message Layout.
It is not allowing to add components, Images or internal Links.

This could be an issue of layout, if I only want to create a new Layout for email, so that the rendering and images and internal links can be added, How do I achieve that.

Can anyone provide a sample cshtml for the layout.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Creating a Layout for EXM is not much different from creating the layout for your normal Sitecore item, To create the layout of your message template:

**Step 1: Create Layout in Sitecore**

- In the Content Editor, navigate to /sitecore/Layout/Layouts/System/Email/ and insert a new layout, for example, NewsletterLayout.

[image]

Notice, we have passed the view layout path, that we will create in step 2.

**Step 2: Create Layout view file in solution**

- Now in your solution, create a razor view file eg. `NewsletterLayout.cshtml`,

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation

@model RenderingModel
<html style="opacity: 1;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta content=" width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport" />
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
    @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("msg-html-title")
    @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("msg-html-style")
</head>
<body>
    <table bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("newsletter-header")
                    @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("newsletter-body")
                    @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("footer")

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Step 3: Branch Templates and Data Templates in Sitecore**

- Now you need to create a new branch template or you can duplicate the existing ones from this path: Templates/Branches/System/Email/Messages

[image]

- Assign your custom layout on Message Root.
  [image]
- Create a new data template at `Templates/System/Email/Messages/Inner Content` and add the required field to this template.

[image]

Refer to [this](https://sitecorewithraman.wordpress.com/2021/10/07/custom-email-templates-for-sitecore-exm/) blog for more details.